# Riemannian metrics with discrete isometry group

Tags: differential-geometry

Does anybody knows an example of a Riemannian metric on a manifold (other than the compact nonpositive curvature case) whose isometry group is discrete? How about such a Riemannian metric with postive curvature?

Comment: What about a (triaxial) ellipsoid? Doesn't that have only $8$ isometries?

Comment: What you note is not true! an ellipsoid have a continuous symmetry group. The rotations about a single axial  forms a subgroup of the isometry group. These groups are continuous!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_symmetry_in_three_dimensions . "$D_{2h}$, [2,2], (*222) of order 8 is the symmetry group of a cuboid" (or of a triaxial ellipsoid). By the way, "triaxial" means the 3 axes are different, so it doesn't have rotation symmetry. The 8 symmetries are 3 reflections (in $xy$, $xz$, $yz$ planes), 3 rotations (180 degrees), 1 inversion $(x,y,z)\mapsto(-x,-y,-z)$, and 1 identity. This is extrinsic geometry, but I believe the intrinsic curvature has the same symmetry.

Comment: Dear friend! 
What you trying to say is that, there are 8 conjugacy classes of discrete subgroups of the Euclidean group Isom(E^3). These groups are called "Crystallographic groups" or "space groups". It is traditionally known that the Crystallographic groups are symmetry groups for some regular polydedron. This is not the answer of my question anyway!

Comment: No, the crystallographic groups have translations. And I'm talking about a single discrete subgroup (or a single conjugacy class) of Isom(E^3) with 8 elements. But my point remains, that a triaxial ellipsoid does not have continuous rotation symmetry.

Comment: What about an ellipsoid with a circular cutting section?

Comment: Yes. But that's not "triaxial". It is called a "spheroid", a special type of ellipsoid which has more symmetry.

Comment: OK, what Riemannian metric do you endow the triaxial ellipsoid?

Comment: By the way, I should correct " It is traditionally known that the Crystallographic groups are symmetry groups for some regular polydedron. " to 
 It is traditionally known that the finite Crystallographic groups are symmetry groups for some regular polydedron. The word "finite" was missing!

Comment: The induced Euclidean metric on the surface $$(x,y,z)=(a\cos u\cos v,b\sin u\cos v,c\sin v)$$ where $a>0,b>0,c>0,a\neq b,a\neq c,b\neq c$. Calculate the derivatives of $\vec r=(x,y,z)$ with respect to $u,v$, then take the dot products $\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}=g_{u,v}$ etc., and this forms the metric tensor $g$.

Comment: OK, it has a positive sectional curvature, it is compact, seems to be a good example! Thank you so much!

Comment: Here's a non-compact example: $z=\cos x\cos y$. (It looks like a wavy ocean.) It has a 2D lattice of translation symmetries, and the curvature is both positive and negative. $$g_{x,x}=1+\sin^2x\cos^2y,\quad g_{x,y}=\sin x\cos x\sin y\cos y,\quad g_{y,y}=1+\cos^2x\sin^2y$$

Answer (score 1):

A kind of dumb example (i.e. it is easily broken by requiring your manifold to be complete): You can take $X =S^2$ with the usual round metric, and then remove 3 linearly independent vectors (in the ambient space) from it $\{x,y,z \}= A$. $Y = X \setminus A$.

Note that each isometry of $Y$ extends to an isometry of $S^2$. (Proof: If you have an isometry $f : Y \to Y$, you get $g = i \circ f : Y \to S^2$, by inclusion $i : Y \to S^2$. Next, since $S^2$ is complete and $i \circ f$ is an isometry, this extends continuously to a map $h : S^2 \to S^2$ (universal property of the completion of a metric space). Now, if $h$ was not an isometry, we could find $x,y \in S^2$ so that $d( h(x) , h(y) ) \not = d(x,y)$. But we can take $x_n, y_n \in Y$ that converge to $x,y$ repectively, and we know that $d(h(x_n),h(y_n)) = d(x_n,y_n)$, letting $n \to \infty$ gives a contradiction. The fact that $h$ is surjective now follows because $Y$ is dense in $S^2$ and the image of $S^2$ is compact.)

In particular, since all isometries of $S^2$ are linear, it follows that all isometries of $Y$ are restrictions of linear maps.

Moreover, an isometry of $Y$ (thought of as an extension to $S^2$) must preserve $A$, and since all the isometries are linear and $A$ contains a set of linearly independent vectors, each isometry is determined by the restriction to $A$.

This gives an injection $isom(Y) \to S_3 = Aut(A)$, which implies that the former is finite, and in particular discrete.

(So, you may want to require that the manifold be complete, which breaks this example.)